# Spacing between the operands of an Infix-to-Postfix program in C

Tags: c, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I've searched the site to see if there are any similar questions to mine, but I can't seem to find one which offers a working solution. Below is the code to a fully functional *infix to postfix* converter for arithmetic syntax.

The issue is that if the user enters a string such as `23+89`, the infix output is `2389+`. This is of course correct, however I wish to add separators between the operands to distinguish between `23` and `89`. How can this be implemented with the array I am using? Do I need to add a whitespace character between the operands in the array? How can this be achieved?

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100 // maximum number of input characters

int precedence(char x);

struct stack
{
    char my_stack[MAX];
    int pointer;
};

int precedence(char x)
{
   if(x == '(')
       return(0);
   if(x == '+' || x == '-')
       return(1);
   if(x == '*' || x == '/')
       return(2);
   return(3);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stack S;
    S.pointer = 0;
    char c;
    char output[MAX]; // stores output
    int out_count = 0; // stores no. of characters of output
    char data; // stores data being popped off the stack

    printf("Enter an expression to check:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    while(('\n' != (c=getchar())))
    {
        if(isdigit(c)) // if an operand is found print to screen
        {
            output[out_count] = c;
            out_count++;
        }
        else if(c == '(') // if ( is found push on stack
        {
            S.pointer = S.pointer +1;
            S.my_stack[S.pointer] = c;
        }
        else if(c == ')') // if ) is found pop stack until ( is found
        {
            while(!(S.my_stack[S.pointer] == '('))
            {
                data = S.my_stack[S.pointer];
                output[out_count] = data;
                out_count++;
                S.pointer = S.pointer -1;
            }
            S.pointer = S.pointer -1; // pop the extra (
        }
        else if(c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '+' || c == '-')
        {
            if((S.pointer) == 0)
            {
                S.pointer = S.pointer +1;
                S.my_stack[S.pointer] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                if(precedence(S.my_stack[S.pointer]) > precedence(c))
                {
                    // pop stack
                    int i;
                    for(i=(S.pointer); i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        if(c == '(' || c == ')')
                            continue;
                        output[out_count] = c;
                        out_count++;
                    }
                    S.pointer = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // push c on stack
                    S.pointer = S.pointer +1;
                    S.my_stack[S.pointer] = c;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    int j = S.pointer;
    while(j != 0)
    {
        if(S.my_stack[j] == '(')
            continue;
        output[out_count] = S.my_stack[j];
        out_count++;
        j--;
    }

    output[out_count+1] = '\0';
    int k=0;
    while(output[k] != '\0') // go through output array and print
    {
        printf("%c", output[k]);
        k++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious: why `()` sometimes around return values like `return(3);`?

Answer (score 0):

> 23+89, the infix output is 2389+. This is of course correct,

Well, no.   2389 is not the same as 23 and 89.

You could either add whitespace, or an explicit "push" operator.  HP calculators often use an up arrow ↑ symbol to show that operation.

Comment: Correct in the sense that the logic behind the code is correct. How can I implement this explicit "push operator"? I'm not sure I follow what you mean.

Comment: @LukeCollins:  By outputting `23+89 converts to 23↑89+` (if not limited to Ascii) or `23+89 converts to 23 push 89+` (if you are).